# How to sort group of nodes in one line using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Below is my xml

```
<products>
    <product>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <item>Pencil</item>
        <price>20</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>25</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

i need output like below

```
product_name       price     remark
Pen                10        Pen+Pencil+Bag
Pencil             20        Pen+Pencil+Bag
Bag                25        Pen+Pencil+Bag
```

How i do `remark` as group in xslt 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSortedNames">
  <xsl:call-template name="sortedItemList"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:text>product_name&#9;price&#9;remark</xsl:text>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
   <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="product">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat('&#xA;', item, '&#9;', price, '&#9;', $vSortedNames)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="sortedItemList">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/product">
   <xsl:sort select="price" data-type="number"/>
  <xsl:if test="not(position() = 1)">+</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <item>Pen</item>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <item>Pencil</item>
        <price>20</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <item>Bag</item>
        <price>25</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
product_name    price   remark
Pen 10  Pen+Pencil+Bag
Pencil  20  Pen+Pencil+Bag
Bag 25  Pen+Pencil+Bag
```